# QuickLatex stopped working in Wordpress without specific error

Tags: wordpress, latex

I am using QuickLatex plugin in Wordpress and it has been working very well. Recently, however, I noticed that it does not show the Latex content in my weblog  (for instance: http://alipourmousavi.com/blog/index.php/2017/09/22/multi-row-and-multi-column-table-with-background-color-in-latex/#comment-3). I have always had "Cache images locally" on, as recommended by the package author. When I carefully observe the loading process, I see that the pictures rendered by QuickLatex show up for a fraction of a second and then disappear. I checked the console debugging and I see the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

WebSocket connection to 'wss://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub/wpcom/me/newest-note-data' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
```

I googled with different keywords and I couldn't find any solution to the problem. Really appreciate if somebody has any idea how to fix it.

Comment: Seems like a known bug: https://github.com/Automattic/pinghub/issues/8

Comment: @Michael: Awesome, I deactivated and then reactivated JetPack and the issue is solved.

Comment: Not sure if that's your solution, from the comments at github: "That doesn't directly fix the problem per se. The issue is if you're not actively logged into WordPress.com, the 403 is returned (as the socket is using your WordPress.com session). Cycling Jetpack works only because you're logging into WordPress.com as part of the process.

You can test this by having a site that works without the 403, logging out completely from wp.com, then seeing a 403. Log back into WordPress.com and all is good again."

Comment: @Michael: Yes I read that comment too. However, I tried my blog posts on the machines that I've never logged into my WP account, it works perfectly (it was not working before reactivation of JetPack). I tried to follow another comment in that post, to turn off the notification in the package, but I did not have that options within the package installed on my WP.